# PHP sessions sharing - subdomain as entry point

Tags: php, session, session-variables, subdomain

I have a landing page like:

subdomain.mydomain.com

and  there I assigned a few session vars, but now the problem is in one point user is redirected to mydomian.com  and all session vars are lost.

I have tried  ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.mydomain.com' );  and htaccess and php.ini fixes, but NOTHING works.... and NO ERROR is generated, so I am kind of puzzled what's going on ?

Comment: Is the subdomain hosted on the same server as the domain?  The method you are using (with `.domain.com`) should work if they are within the same folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to append this code, every domain, before starting session

```
session_name("WebsiteID");
```

replace WebsiteID with your favorite value.

Comment: not working... this drives me crazy.... I tried everything I found... and have no suhoshin enabled....

Comment: I was having this situation before, just copy this code to before start session every php file. session_name("WebsiteID"); then session_start(); will work. It was solved the my problem.